# What should the name of my non-boot partition be?

Tags: raspbian, backup, partition

I am trying to restore a backup to a new SD card. Because I appear to have used an obscure backup process, the contents of the `boot` partition are in one place, and the contents of the *other* partition in another. I am trying to replicate the old SD card by replicating the original partition structure and then dumping the files into the new SD card.

However, I don't know what the *name* of the other partition should be, or whether I need to respect any other parameters of the old SD card in order that it works properly. I *think* it was something along the lines of `sfd1` (something like that), but I can't remember for certain.

In order to reinstate the backup, I presume I need to restore the `boot` partition and the other partition to whatever the previous name was. Can anyone tell me what the *default* name of the other partition is likely to be, or whether I can find the correct name by searching perhaps the content of the `boot` backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should the name of my non-boot partition be?

It doesn't matter.  As far as I've ever noticed it doesn't have a name.  It certainly isn't required for anything.

What is important is that it contain the **correct filesystem type**, which is `ext4`.  Beware that MS Windows does not play nice (or, at all) by default with ext4 filesystems and unless you find some software to make it happen, you cannot do this from a Windows box.

Conversely, the boot partition must FAT32/VFAT and the device must be formatted with an [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) (the last part is probably normal for any SD card oriented tool).

Comment: Thanks. For the benefit of future readers, I am setting up from a Mac, and I use an app called `fuse-ext2` to help me write an `ext4` partition.